# Whenever an app tries to authenticate with Facebook, the dialog is in a foreign language

Tags: ios, facebook

As you can see whenever an iOS app tries to authenticate me with Facebook the dialog is in Indonesian (I think). I've never set anything to that language, and in iOS and on Facebook my language is set to English.

I figure Masuk is something like "allow" but I don't know what kind of permissions I'm granting the app, so I would like to get these dialogs in English.

[image: Facebook authenticating in wrong language]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug by Facebook - you can track the status of it here: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/407246299295529?browse=search_4fa410ea79db26337556383

Comment: Great: "Latest response from Facebook: Bumping priority to high"